# Unable to insert data into database in oop way

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm trying to add car in to database using oop way.

Can someone point out the mistake here?If I don't extend the connection class, how do I access the method in the class?Why object pdo is not working in class car?

```
<?php
class connection
{
    public $servername = "localhost";
    public $username = "root";
    public $password = "mypassword";
    public $dbname = "carrental";
    public $port="3306";

    function addConnection()
    {
      try {
      $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servername;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }
      $pdo->query("use $this->dbname");
    }
}
class car extends connection
{
    public $name;
    public $maker;
    public $type;
    public $colour;
    public $passanger;

    function __construct($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4,$param5)
    {
        $this->name=$param1;
        $this->maker=$param2;
        $this->type=$param3;
        $this->colour=$param4;
        $this->passanger=$param5;
        echo "name is {$this->name}.Maker is {$this->maker}.";
    }
    function addCar()
    {

        $this->addConnection();
        echo $this->username;
        $sql="INSERT INTO car(car_name,car_maker,car_colour,num_passanger)VALUES(:$param1,:$param2, :$param3,:$param4,:$param5)";
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(
        ':param1'=>$this->name,
        ':param2'=>$this->maker,
        ':param3'=>$this->type,
        ':param4'=>$this->colour,
        ':param5'=>$this->passanger
        ));
        echo "affected rows ".$stmt->rowCount();
    }
}

$car1=new car("Honda Accord","Honda","4 wheeler","Red",5);
$car1->addCar();

?>
```

Comment: When creating the `$pdo` variable nothing happens. You should make `$pdo` a property and access it for queries.

Comment: With such a logic implemented, I would rather make **connection** a **static class** without extending it. The other solutions you have is either create a `$pdo object` in your connection class (but you will most likely be re-calling and re-loading it every single time you create an extended class object) or you can just set the `addConnection()` function to **return** a `pdo object`. Also, I would recommend you to use an interface (or an abstract class) instead for such scopes, because you need to create some sort of "rules" for your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public $pdo;

function addConnection()
{
  try {
      $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servername;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
      $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

  $this->pdo->query("use $this->dbname");
}
```

---

```
function addCar()
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO car(car_name,car_maker,car_colour,num_passanger)VALUES(:$param1,:$param2, :$param3,:$param4,:$param5)";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
    ':param1'=>$this->name,
    ':param2'=>$this->maker,
    ':param3'=>$this->type,
    ':param4'=>$this->colour,
    ':param5'=>$this->passanger
    ));
    echo "affected rows ".$stmt->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: I got this error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\carRental\index.php on line 53

Comment: Did you not forget add 'public $pdo;' into 'connection' class?

Comment: add this into car contructor: $this->addConnection();

Answer (score 0):

Just like Daniel has suggested, make `$pdo` a public property of class `connection` and have the method `addConnection()` assign a value to this property:

```
public $pdo;

function addConnection()
{
  try {
      $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servername;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
      $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
  } 
  $this->pdo->query("use $this->dbname");
}
```

Now access this property in your query method calls:

```
function addCar()
{
    if(!isset($this->pdo))
        $this->addConnection();
    $sql="INSERT INTO car(car_name,car_maker,car_colour,num_passanger)VALUES(:$param1,:$param2, :$param3,:$param4,:$param5)";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
    ':param1'=>$this->name,
    ':param2'=>$this->maker,
    ':param3'=>$this->type,
    ':param4'=>$this->colour,
    ':param5'=>$this->passanger
    ));
    echo "affected rows ".$stmt->rowCount();
}
```

Another alternative is to have a separate PHP file which sets a `global` PDO object and then include this file in any other necessary files and use the exposed variable.

#### Connections.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "carrental";
$port="3306";

$pdo=getConnected();

function getConnected(){
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$this>servername;port=$this>port;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $pdo;
}
?>
```

Note that you could further abstract the credentials into a `credentials.php` file and the include this within `connections.php`.

#### car.php

```
<?php  
include_once('Connections.php');
class car
{
    public $name;
    public $maker;
    public $type;
    public $colour;
    public $passanger;

    function __construct($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4,$param5)
    {
        $this->name=$param1;
        $this->maker=$param2;
        $this->type=$param3;
        $this->colour=$param4;
        $this->passanger=$param5;
        echo "name is {$this->name}.Maker is {$this->maker}.";
    }
    function addCar()
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO car(car_name,car_maker,car_colour,num_passanger)VALUES(:$param1,:$param2, :$param3,:$param4,:$param5)";
        $stmt = $GLOBALS['pdo']->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(
        ':param1'=>$this->name,
        ':param2'=>$this->maker,
        ':param3'=>$this->type,
        ':param4'=>$this->colour,
        ':param5'=>$this->passanger
        ));
        echo "affected rows ".$stmt->rowCount();
    }
}
$car1=new car("Honda Accord","Honda","4 wheeler","Red",5);
$car1->addCar();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

$this->addConnection();
Try

```
  $this->conn = parent::addConnection();        

  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
```